# LinearLayout fill equally textviews with given space value

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a design requirements which are as follows:

There are three text views with a variable text and the space between them is 10dp. Text views and spacers must be part of a blank container whose width is equal to the screen width.

Below an image which represent the requirements:

[image]

In my implementation, I use LinearLayout which matches the parent width, text views have the weight equal to 1 and a space views between the container and the text views whose weight is equal to 1.

My problem is that the text views are not equal on the screen due to a different text length. Below my LinearLayout definition.

[image]

**My question is:** Is is possible to write a LinearLyout view like the requested by the designer or I should write it programmatically?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_infrastructure_status"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separator_under_course_list"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7"

        >

    <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Parking \n open"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Restaurant\nopen"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shop\nopen"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all the `View`s that you assign `weight` you must set:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

but the problem is that this way all the `Space`s and the `TextView`s will have the same width. 
I changed `android:weightSum` from 7 to 19 and gave weight 5 to each `TextView`.
 So:

```
1(Space) + 5(TextView) + 1(Space) + 5(TextView) + 1(Space) + 5(TextView) + 1(Space) = 19
```

You can adjust it as you like.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separator_under_course_list"
    android:id="@+id/view_infrastructure_status"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="19">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Parking \n open"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Restaurant\nopen"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Shop\nopen"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_width='0dp'` with the `TextView`s if you are using weights with a horizontal LinearLayout.

Also, if you have to use `Space`, take care of the textview to space ratio when assigning weights. For example, in your case, the weight distribution may be a weight of 1 for a space and a weight of 3 for a textview. Change the value of `layout_weightsum` accordingly.

Example xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_infrastructure_status"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separator_under_course_list"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="xx">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Parking \n open"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bng_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    ....
</LinearLayout>
```